# Qt application crashing during back end

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

So I'm just making a *supposedly* simple program to get started with Qt. I had the backend of 2048 pre-made from some previous practice work, and on its own, it runs well enough. Without fail, the program crashes at the `if(!t->sameAs(board[t->pos-dimen]) && board[t->pos-dimen]->value != 0){` or similar line, of the `can*Direction*()` functions regardless of the direction. Furthermore, the program *does not* throw a useful error. What needs to change, or how else does the back end need to be implemented?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    game* g = new game();

    g->printBoard();

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include "game.h"


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    game* g;
    void updateLCD();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    update();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete g;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Up)
    {
        g->moveUp();
        updateLCD();
    }
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down)
    {
        g->moveDown();
        updateLCD();
    }
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Left)
    {
        g->moveLeft();
        updateLCD();
    }
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Right)
    {
        g->moveRight();
        updateLCD();
    }
}

void MainWindow::updateLCD(){
    ui->LCD00->display(g->getTile(0));
    ui->LCD10->display(g->getTile(1));
    ui->LCD20->display(g->getTile(2));
    ui->LCD30->display(g->getTile(3));
    ui->LCD01->display(g->getTile(4));
    ui->LCD11->display(g->getTile(5));
    ui->LCD21->display(g->getTile(6));
    ui->LCD31->display(g->getTile(7));
    ui->LCD02->display(g->getTile(8));
    ui->LCD12->display(g->getTile(9));
    ui->LCD22->display(g->getTile(10));
    ui->LCD32->display(g->getTile(11));
    ui->LCD30->display(g->getTile(12));
    ui->LCD31->display(g->getTile(13));
    ui->LCD32->display(g->getTile(14));
    ui->LCD33->display(g->getTile(15));
}
```

**game.h**

```
#ifndef game_hpp
#define game_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

class game{

private:
    const static int TOTALTILES = 16;

    struct tile{
        int pos;
        bool hasVal = false;
        int value = 0;
        int dimen;
        bool sameAs(tile* t){ return t->value == value; }
    };

    tile* board[TOTALTILES];

    bool allLeft();
    bool allRight();
    bool allUp();
    bool allDown();
    void generate();

    bool canUp(tile*);
    bool canLeft(tile*);
    bool canRight(tile*);
    bool canDown(tile*);

    void moveTileUp(tile*);
    void moveTileDown(tile*);
    void moveTileLeft(tile*);
    void moveTileRight(tile*);

    int dimen;

public:
    game();
    void moveUp();
    void moveDown();
    void moveLeft();
    void moveRight();
    void printBoard();

    int getTile(int i);
};

#endif /* game_hpp */
```

**game.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "game.h"

game::game(){
    dimen = log2(TOTALTILES);

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < TOTALTILES; i++){
        board[i] = new tile();
        board[i]->pos = i;
        board[i]->dimen = dimen;
    }
    generate();
    generate();
}

void game::moveUp(){
    if(!allUp()){
        while(!allUp()){
            for(int i = 0; i < TOTALTILES; i++){
                moveTileUp(board[i]);
            }
        }
        generate();
    }
}

void game::moveDown(){
    if(!allDown()){

        while(!allDown()){
            for(int i = TOTALTILES - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                moveTileDown(board[i]);
            }
        }
        generate();
    }
}

void game::moveLeft(){
    if(!allLeft()){
        while(!allLeft()){
            for(int i = 0; i < TOTALTILES; i++){
                moveTileLeft(board[i]);
            }
        }
        generate();
    }
}

void game::moveRight(){
    if(!allRight()){
        while(!allRight()){
            for(int i = 0; i < TOTALTILES; i++){
                moveTileRight(board[i]);
            }
        }
        generate();
    }
}

void game::moveTileUp(tile* t){
    if(canUp(t)){
        tile* other = board[t->pos-dimen];
        if(t->sameAs(other)){
            other->value++;
            t->value = 0;
        } else {
            other->value = t->value;
            t->value = 0;
        }
    }
}

void game::moveTileDown(tile* t){
    if(canDown(t)){
        tile* other = board[t->pos+dimen];
        if(t->sameAs(other)){
            other->value++;
            t->value = 0;
        } else {
            other->value = t->value;
            t->value = 0;
        }
    }
}

void game::moveTileLeft(tile* t){
    if(canLeft(t)){
        tile* other = board[t->pos-1];
        if(t->sameAs(other)){
            other->value++;
            t->value = 0;
        } else {
            other->value = t->value;
            t->value = 0;
        }
    }
}

void game::moveTileRight(tile* t){
    if(canRight(t)){
        tile* other = board[t->pos+1];
        if(t->sameAs(other)){
            other->value++;
            t->value = 0;
        } else {
            other->value = t->value;
            t->value = 0;
        }
    }
}

void game::printBoard(){
    for(int i = 0; i < dimen; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dimen; j++){
            if(board[(i*dimen) + j]->value == 0){
                std::cout << "- ";
            } else std::cout << pow(2, board[(i*dimen) + j]->value) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void game::generate(){
    bool ungenerated = true;
    int pos = rand() % 16;

    while(ungenerated){
        if(board[pos]->value == 0){
            if(rand() % (TOTALTILES/2) == 0){
                if(rand() % 2 == 0) board[pos]->value = 1;
                else board[pos]->value = 2;
                ungenerated = false;
            }
        }

        pos = rand() % 16;
    }
}

bool game::allUp(){
    for(int i = 0; i < TOTALTILES; i++){
        if(canUp(board[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool game::allDown(){
    for(int i = 0; i < TOTALTILES; i++){
        if(canDown(board[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool game::allLeft(){
    for(int i = 0; i < TOTALTILES; i++){
        if(canLeft(board[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool game::allRight(){
    for(int i = 0; i < TOTALTILES; i++){
        if(canRight(board[i])){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool game::canUp(tile* t){
    if(t->value == 0) return false;
    else {
        if(t->pos < dimen){
            return false;
        }
        if(!t->sameAs(board[t->pos-dimen]) && board[t->pos-dimen]->value != 0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

bool game::canDown(tile* t){
    if(t->value == 0) return false;
    else {
        if(t->pos >= TOTALTILES-dimen){
            return false;
        }
        if(!t->sameAs(board[t->pos+dimen]) && board[t->pos+dimen]->value != 0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

bool game::canLeft(tile* t){
    if(t->value == 0) return false;
    else {
        if(t->pos % dimen == 0){
            return false;
        }
        if(!t->sameAs(board[t->pos-1]) && board[t->pos-1]->value != 0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

bool game::canRight(tile* t){
    if(t->value == 0) return false;
    else {
        if(t->pos % dimen == (dimen - 1)){
            return false;
        }
        if(!t->sameAs(board[t->pos+1]) && board[t->pos+1]->value != 0){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

int game::getTile(int i){
    int ret = pow(2,board[i]->value);

    if(ret > 0) return ret;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use a debugger to look at the values of all the relevant variables that are used in the line that crashes.  Also, maybe you could post the generated C++ source code of Ui::MainWindow so that I can try to reproduce your problem here?

Comment: Also, I don't know what sort of inputs (e.g. mouse clicks and keyboard events) you are sending to the program to make it crash.  You should try to make it crash by calling functions on the game object directly from `main`.  Then you can get rid of MainWindow, which makes it much easier for others to reproduce your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after 'sleeping on it.' It had to do with the location in memory of the game, and from where it was being accessed. The game had to be *instantiated within* the mainwindow class in order for other parts of main window to use it.

Furthermore, just a tip for others for the future. The LCD objects weren't updating for two reasons:

- There is an `update()` function build into widgets. So the compiler doesn't freak out if you write `update()` instead of, say, `updateLCD()`.
- You have to call functions on the object using 'this'. The program needs to know that this update is happening on the item it is being called from.